# Quotient rule simplification

Tags: calculus

After housing the quotient rule on

$y=(4x)/(1-x)^3$ I got $4(1-x)^3 - 4x(-3+3x^2)$

but I'm not sure where to go next

Comment: you can go to new york, What do you mean where to go next??

Comment: Well that would be nice but I have to figure this out first, the answer stated in the book is $4(2x +1) / (1-x)^4$ So ideally I'd like to get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done using the product rule, if you set it to $y=4x(1-x)^{-3}$. However, I'll use the quotient rule which is defined as:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{u}{v}=\frac{v\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2}$$

Now for your problem:

$$y=\frac{\underbrace{4x}_{u}}{\underbrace{(1-x)^3}_{v}}\\ \frac{du}{dx}=4\\\frac{dv}{dx}=-3(1-x)^2$$

Hence:

$$y'=\frac{(1-x)^3(4)-(4x)(-3(1-x)^2)}{((1-x)^3)^2}$$

Simplified, it is:
$$y'=\frac{8x+4}{(x-1)^4}$$

Comment: That's be a really nice solution except I have to use the quotient rule in this case

Comment: @Paul I did use the quotient rule, I just said as a disclaimer that you can also use the product rule.

Comment: ah sorry I misread that completely, thanks for the help